# Finding null field with two data tables and date table joined

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to do this SQL query, but I'm at a loss. I think I am getting in over my head. 
I have three tables:
1. datetable, which contains lists of month/year up to year 2020. column is 'thedate'
2. A table containing a list of lectures. A date() field is one column, named "month"
3. A log table, which contains individual rows of data on a month to month basis. i.e Each user has their own row of data for each month of the year.

I would like to take table #2, find if there is a lecture assigned for month x, then take table #3, find the row which corresponds to month x and particular user, then see if column 'hopkins' (a part of table 3) is null or not. I hope this makes a little bit of sense. I've figured out how to use the datetable to find missing rows in table #2, but I haven't figured out how to do this above.
Thanks!

Comment: Please export your DDL with the command `DESCRIBE tablename` of mysql

Comment: Not enough character space to insert here, so I took a screengrab.

http://i.imgur.com/PpSvpRo.jpg

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com to show table and query

Comment: Ah great. I have it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e03c.  Data is included, but it's all dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a left join from `eval` to `hopkins` and then a test on the field:

```
select e.uid,
       max(case when h.name is null then 0 else 1 end) as isInHopkins
from eval e left outer join
     hopkins h
     on year(e.month) = year(h.month) and
        month(e.month) = month(h.month)
group by e.uid;
```

If the `hopkins.id` is supposed to related to the user, then you would want to add `and e.uid = h.id` to the `on` clause.

If this doesn't give you what you want, then please edit your question to provide sample results for the SQL Fiddle data.

Comment: I believe I have it. It's not the most beautiful, but it works.
`SELECT thedate
  FROM datetable
  LEFT JOIN eval on eval.month = datetable.thedate
  LEFT JOIN hopkins on hopkins.month = datetable.thedate
  WHERE eval.hopkins IS NULL
  and uid = '1'
  and thedate between '2013-07-01' and DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')`